# Error when i perform the operation matchTemplate error(-215)

Tags: c++, opencv, correlation, template-matching

I wrote a program to match a patchimage with source image..I am successful in creating patch image and gives no error when i compile the file. But when i want to display it; it shows the following error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed(corrsize.height<=img.rows+templ.rows-1 && corrsize.width<=img.cols+templ.cols-1) in crossCorr, file /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.2-1precise-20130312-1308/.../templmatch.cpp line 70

terminate after called after throwing an instance of cv::Exception
/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.2-1precise-20130312-1308/.../templmatch.cpp:70:error(-215)
corrsize.height<=img.rows+templ.rows-1 && corrsize.width<=img.cols+templ.cols-1) in function crossCorr
```

My code is

```
Mat correlation=Mat::zeros(detected_edges.rows+patch.rows- 1,detected_edges.cols+patch.cols-1,CV_8UC1);
matchTemplate(detected_edges,patch,correlation,CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
namedWindow("corre",0);
imshow("corre",correlation);
waitKey(100);
```

where detected_edges is my source image and patch is my template image..